# Locked from Rotating/Scaling?

Tags: transforms

I just started Blender yesterday, following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFzIbz2FN28 and at 8:30, he's made a cylinder and scales it down to flashlight handle size by pressing "S" and moving the mouse.

For whatever reason, pressing "S" suddenly didn't allow me to scale with the mouse despite it working earlier in the tutorial.  I was able to enter the values manually to scale it, but then it came time to rotate it.  He did so with "R" as I had previously, but now it also wasn't working for me.

When I press "S" or "R", the cursor changes to look the way it should when I'd be scaling or rotating, but moving the mouse has no effect on the shape itself.  When I press "R", the cursor changes, and moving the mouse causes a "Rot: -250" for example to appear in the upper left corner if I've moved the mouse in such a way that it **should** have rotated -250 degrees.  The change just isn't visible on the canvas area.

As I'm new to Blender, I assume that I've inadvertently selected some sort of "Lock from Transforming" option and disallowed myself from transforming objects with the letter shortcut and mouse movement.

It's not the end of the world because I can still change the rotation by typing in the values on the right in the "Transform" window, but I'd still like to know what's wrong.

Opening a new Blender file confirms that I can transform as intended there, so it must be some option I've selected in the practice file that's preventing me.  Does anyone know what it is, or what else I might be doing wrong?

Not even clicking the "Transform" button on the left and dragging one of the axis circles works. It should have rotated but it's still just sitting straight up.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps you enabled *Transform Only Origin*. Shortcut to turn it on/off is `Ctrl` + `.`

Comment: It still didn't work whether that was on or off.  I'm relatively certain it wasn't enabled.  I attached a screenshot of how using the Transform button options isn't working either.

Comment: Hello :). Hard to say without seeing the file. Just to make sure - top right corner, Options Menu, make sure it's all unchecked.